# Targeting text value from link for multiple links in one output

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, hyperlink, target

I can't find/think of a way to solve this problem. 
I have a list of links outputted by a php script and I need to get the text value from the item (link) that's been clicked.

Here is the php part that outputs data:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT NAME FROM ccm WHERE NAME LIKE '$value%'");


    while( $run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $name = $run['NAME'];



    echo '<a id="rez_link" onClick="klik();">'.$name.'</a>';
    }
```

And here are some of my attempts to fetch the .text() from the link that's been clicked:

```
var value = $('a#rez_link').text(); //this one targets every text if there are multiple search result from the query
var value = jQuery(this).find("a").text(); //this one returns nothing
```

So how do I do it?
Maybe I should modify the php script so that it outputs new links with id=""+i and then target them like that in jQuery or something like that.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have more anchor tags with same id

```
echo '<a id="rez_link" onClick="klik();">'.$name.'</a>';
```

it's better to use class instead

```
echo '<a class="rez_link">'.$name.'</a>';
$(function() {
 $(".rez_link").on("click",function()
    {
        var text = $(this).text();
        alert(text);
    }

});
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks and how do I access it from jQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
$('.rez_link').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkText = $(this).text();
    $('#show').text(linkText);
    });
});
```

[It's this what you try to do ?](http://jsfiddle.net/cyyax/)